# Assertion error, eventhough my return value is the same

Tags: python

```
def interleave(s1,s2): #This function interleaves s1,s2 together
    guess = 0
    total = 0
    while (guess < len(s1)) and (guess < len(s2)):
        x = s1[guess]
        y = s2[guess]
        m = x + y
        print ((m),end ="")
        guess += 1
    if (len(s1) == len(s2)):
        return ("")
    elif(len(s1) > len(s2)):
        return (s1[guess:])
    elif(len(s2) > len(s1)):
        return (s2[guess:])

print (interleave("Smlksgeneg n a!", "a ie re gsadhm"))
```

For some reason, my test function gives an assertion error eventhough the output is the same as the code below.
Eg - "Smlksgeneg n a!", "a ie re gsadhm" returns "Sam likes green eggs and ham!"
but an assertion error still comes out

```
def testInterleave():
    print("Testing interleave()...", end="")
    assert(interleave("abcdefg", "abcdefg")) == ("aabbccddeeffgg")
    assert(interleave("abcde", "abcdefgh") == "aabbccddeefgh")
    assert(interleave("abcdefgh","abcde") == "aabbccddeefgh")
    assert(interleave("Smlksgeneg n a!", "a ie re gsadhm") ==
                  "Sam likes green eggs and ham!")
    assert(interleave("","") == "")
    print("Passed!")

testInterleave()
```

Comment: What values of s1 and s2 give you the assertion error? What is the exact error and traceback? How can you get an assertion error when there are no assert statements in your code?

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing what is printed by interleave() from what is returned by it. The assert is testing the returned value. For example, when s1 and s2 are the same length, your code prints the interleave (on the `print((m),end="")` line) but returns an empty string (in the line `return ("")`

If you want interleave to return the interleaved string, you need to collect the x and y variables (not very well named if they are always holding characters) into a single string and return that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your function just prints the interleaved portion of the resulting string, it doesn't return it, it only returns the tail of the longer string.

Here's a repaired and simplified version of your code. You don't need to do those `if... elif` tests. Also, your code has a lot of superfluous parentheses (and one misplaced parenthesis), which I've removed.

```
def interleave(s1, s2): 
    ''' Interleave strings s1 and s2 '''
    guess = 0
    result = ""
    while (guess < len(s1)) and (guess < len(s2)):
        x = s1[guess]
        y = s2[guess]
        result += x + y
        guess += 1
    return result + s1[guess:] + s2[guess:]   

def testInterleave():
    print("Testing interleave()...", end="")
    assert interleave("abcdefg", "abcdefg") == "aabbccddeeffgg"
    assert interleave("abcde", "abcdefgh") == "aabbccddeefgh"
    assert interleave("abcdefgh","abcde") == "aabbccddeefgh"
    assert (interleave("Smlksgeneg n a!", "a ie re gsadhm") 
        == "Sam likes green eggs and ham!")
    assert interleave("", "") == ""
    print("Passed!")

print(interleave("Smlksgeneg n a!", "a ie re gsadhm"))

testInterleave()
```

**output**

```
Sam likes green eggs and ham!
Testing interleave()...Passed!
```

Here's a slightly improved version of `interleave`. It uses a list to store the result, rather than using repeated string concatenation. Using lists to build string like this is a common Python practice because it's more efficient than repeated string concatenation using `+` or `+=`; OTOH,`+` and `+=` on strings have been optimised so that they're fairly efficient for short strings (up to 1000 chars or so).

```
def interleave(s1, s2): 
    result = []
    i = 0
    for i, t in enumerate(zip(s1, s2)):
        result.extend(t)
    i += 1
    result.extend(s1[i:] + s2[i:])
    return ''.join(result)
```

That `i = 0` is necessary in case either `s1` or `s2` are empty strings. When that happens the `for` loop isn't entered and so `i` won't get assigned a value.

Finally, here's a compact version using a list comprehension and the standard `itertools.zip_longest` function.

```
def interleave(s1, s2):
    return ''.join([u+v for u,v in zip_longest(s1, s2, fillvalue='')])
```

Comment: Thank you so much everyone! Recently started self-learning programming, and I appreciate the help